# Unable to install a Perl module [using Japanese instructions]

Tags: perl

I have intalled the strawberry perl and everything goes well.
However, I could not install a module even if I follow the installation instructions.

```
1. 必要なツールをインストールする．
茶筌をコンパイルするには以下のツールが必要である．
• Darts1 バージョン0.3 以降
• （システムに標準装備されていなければ）libiconv

2. ‘configure’ を実行する．

% ./configure

• Darts のヘッダファイルを指定する場合

% ./configure --with-darts=/usr/local/include
```

The module is located in C:\darts-0.32 and inside the directory there is the configure file.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use code formatting to format your code. Please provide a description of your problem that is more specific that "could not install". What was the output of running the commands you ran? What error messages were displayed?

Comment: Those instruction are in Japanese, not Chinese, btw. Please provide the name of the module, too.

Comment: @Quentin C:\darts-0.32>% ./configure

result: Not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Thank you!

Comment: @ialarmedalien is the name Text::Darts ?

Comment: It looks like you are using the Windows command prompt to run that and it isn't sufficiently UNIX-like to work. Doesn't Strawberry come with its own command prompt?

Comment: @Quentin I've changed to ActiveState Perl, but it has the same problem occurred.

Comment: Why would using ActiveState help? You are (presumably) still using the same command prompt (which is your problem as I pointed out in my previous comment) and one of the main driving forces behind Strawberry was to make it easier to install Perl modules from source instead of using ActiveState's PPM tool!

Comment: @Quentin I think that distinction is above the OP's current level of OS or perl knowledge.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, and I just wanted to have a try. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to install [`Text::Darts`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Darts) and its prerequisite Darts, there are installation instructions on the [author's website](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/darts/index.html) as well as on CPAN. Installation should be done as follows:

```
(change directory to the darts download dir)
% ./configure 
% make
% make check
% make install
```

(or it may be `sudo make install` on your system)

darts is installed to `/usr/local/include/darts.h` by default.

Comment: C:\darts-0.32>% ./configure

result: Not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @DanEng http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: I have already set up the path. But it still appears the same error message.

Comment: If it's not working, the path obviously isn't set up properly. You should start a new question about it as it's a different issue to the perl module installation.

Comment: I've changed to ActiveState Perl, but it has the same problem occurred.

Comment: Your current problem is nothing to do with perl; it's to do with running the `./configure` shell script. What OS are you on? If Windows, have you got a shell interpreter like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed? If so, you can run the script using `sh ./configure`.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet as I've changed to use another program. Thank you for your reply!